# Add XElement to XML file with formatting and indenting

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xelement

**XML**

Source XML

```
<!-- The comment -->
<Root xmlns="http://www.namespace.com">
    <FirstElement>
    </FirstElement>

    <SecondElement>
    </SecondElement>
</Root>
```

Desired XML

```
<!-- The comment -->
<Root xmlns="http://www.namespace.com">
    <FirstElement>
    </FirstElement>

    <SecondElement>
    </SecondElement>

    <ThirdElement>
        <FourthElement>thevalue</FourthElement>
    </ThirdElement>
</Root>
```

Now my output XML is

```
<!-- The comment -->
<Root xmlns="http://www.namespace.com">
    <FirstElement>
    </FirstElement>

    <SecondElement>
    </SecondElement><ThirdElement><FourthElement>thevalue</FourthElement></ThirdElement>
</Root>
```

Note that I need to load the XML with `LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace` as I need to preserve all whitespaces (desired by customer).
The desired output is to put 2 newlines after the last child element of the "root" and add with the proper indent

```
<ThirdElement>
    <FourthElement>thevalue</FourthElement>
</ThirdElement>
```

Any ideas how to realize this?

**Code**

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(sourceXml, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace); //need to preserve all whitespaces
var mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
var ns = xDoc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
mgr.AddNamespace("ns", ns.NamespaceName);

if (xDoc.Root.HasElements)
{
    xDoc.Root.Elements().Last().AddAfterSelf(new XElement(ns + "ThirdElement", new XElement(ns + "FourthElement", "thevalue")));

    using (var xw = XmlWriter.Create(outputXml, new XmlWriterSettings() { OmitXmlDeclaration = true })) //omit xml declaration
        xDoc.Save(xw);
}
```

Comment: Why do you care about the whitespace? It does nothing except increase the amount of data you store.

Comment: @DavidG This is desired by the customer

Comment: You probably won't be able to do anything with the extra newlines, but the [`Indent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.indent(v=vs.110).aspx) setting might make it look slightly better.

Comment: You can add comments to file instead of extra blank lines where you can add comments indicating the end of a child.  I usually add a start comment and end comment to each section of my xml files to make it easier to read by humans.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ideally, you should explain to your client that this really isn't important.

However, if your really need to mess around with whitespace, i'd note that `XText` is what you need. This is another `XObject` that represents text nodes and can be interspersed as part of your content. This is probably a much better approach than string manipulation.

For example:

```
doc.Root.Add(
    new XText("\n\t"),
    new XElement(ns + "ThirdElement",
        new XText("\n\t\t"),
        new XElement(ns + "FourthElement", "thevalue"),
        new XText("\n\t")),
    new XText("\n"));
```

See [this demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BevfN4).

Comment: Thank you! I totally forgot the XText class.

Answer (score 2):

My solution is to beautify just before saving by reparsing the document.

```
string content = XDocument.Parse(xDoc.ToString()).ToString();
File.WriteAllText(file, content, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Comment: Good. Very smart!

Comment: As far as I can see, this will effectively loose the blank lines from the original input.